# `Phaser.GameObjects.Container` seems to force us to use array. Why does it works this way? Is there some consideration under the hood?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to understand how [Phaser.GameObjects.Container](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Container.html) works. Here is the code.

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  create() {
    this.menus = this.add.container();
    var menuItemBlue = new Phaser.GameObjects.Text(this, 10, 30, 'Blue');
    this.menus.add(menuItemBlue);
    console.log(this.menus.length);

    this.menus = this.add.container();
    var menuItemRed = new Phaser.GameObjects.Text(this, 10, 50, 'Red');
    this.menus.add(menuItemRed);
    console.log(this.menus.length);
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 320,
  height: 260,
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

`create()` method adds two items to the container though, the length is always 1.

I also tried this

```
this.menus.add([menuItemBlue, menuItemRed]);
console.log(this.menus.length);
```

which outputs as expected, that is 2.

It seems that if I add items one by one, only the last one is kept by the container. If I want to keep them all, I have to put all the items in an array and then add the array to the container. Is my understanding correct?

Why does `Phaser.GameObjects.Container` work this way? Is there some consideration under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are creating two containers `this.menus = this.add.container();`.
Remove the second *"creation"*, and it works.
*(I took your example and commented the second creating out, and now it works as expected)*

> just in case: `this.add.container()` creates a container, and adds it to the `scene`.

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  create() {
    // First Container
    this.menus = this.add.container();
    var menuItemBlue = new Phaser.GameObjects.Text(this, 10, 30, 'Blue');
    this.menus.add(menuItemBlue);
    console.log(this.menus.length);

    // Second not needed Container
    // this.menus = this.add.container();
    var menuItemRed = new Phaser.GameObjects.Text(this, 10, 50, 'Red');
    this.menus.add(menuItemRed);
    console.log(this.menus.length);
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 320,
  height: 260,
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```